# How to enable/disable or delete modifiers on multiple objects at the same time

Tags: modifiers, transforms, workflow

I have downloaded a nice car model from the web.

But when I move it, some parts deform.
I found out that the cause is the "Shrinkwrap" modifier.
As there are many parts, I do not want to disable or delete it one by one.
Can I do it together?
[image: car model]
[image: parts error]

Comment: This could be done with python so I added a python tag. Someone well versed in python should be able to write a short script that can batch disable and remove modifiers.

Comment: someone did.  That's would be the modifier tools addon I mentioned.

Comment: @Benus I think tags are not meant to reflect how the questions can be answered, but rather to define the global scope of the problem. Otherwise we could add the python tag to pretty much all questions since the python API can almost always be used to solve or help solve problems. (Just my opinion :) )

Comment: Modifier tools doesn't let you batch remove certain modifiers. I should've been more clear on that. And for the python tag, I added it as more of a call for help because batch removing modifiers could can be done with a script of some kind. If that was the wrong thing to do, then woopsies.

Comment: @Benus not a wrong thing, but I think I screwed up and re-deleted the tag. My pad.  Putting it back.

Comment: @MartyFouts  tags really shouldn't be added in accordance to *possible* solutions, but for the actual problem the OP is having. In this case, it is a modifier/ workflow question for the OP, not really a python question for them although very true could be answered with a python solution. hould not be retagged as such unless that is the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Timaroberts good point.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try selecting all objects then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> on the Show in Viewport and Show in Render buttons in the Shrinkwrap Modifiers.

[image]

Comment: This will work for toggling visibility but not for deleting modifiers.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But Franson Wu did state "I do not want to disable or delete it one by one" so I assumed disabling would be alright for him.

Comment: I did it several times and done. that is, I select all, did it, and it remain some parts unchanged, then I did it again, thus after several times, it is done. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If disabling object mode visibility is sufficient, there is a built-in add-on [*Modifier Tools*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/interface/modifier_tools.html) that you can enable.  Once it is enabled a new panel will show up in the modifier tab of the properties editor:

[image: modifier tools panel]

There isn't an equivalent command for disabling viewing in just edit mode or applying to the render, but it would not be difficult to add such commands using Python.

The Add-on also supports batch removing of all modifiers with the *Delete All* option; or applying them with the *Apply All* option.

Note: this is a toggle.  Hitting it when the view is disabled reenables it.  Also, you can apply it to multiple objects at once by selecting all of the objects and clicking the button while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>